# How can the benefit of the feat Mounted Combat be used more than once per round?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, mounted-combat

The benefit of the feat [**Mounted Combat**](http://dndsrd.net/featsAll.html#mounted-combat) says

> Once per round when your mount is hit in combat, you may attempt a Ride check (as a reaction) to negate the hit. The hit is negated if your Ride check result is greater than the opponent’s attack roll. (Essentially, the Ride check result becomes the mount’s Armor Class if it’s higher than the mount’s regular AC.) (*Player's Handbook* 98)

Is there a class feature, magic item, spell, or something else that enables a rider to employ the benefit of the feat Mounted Combat more than once per round or, ideally, *any number* of times per round?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## There Are Two Abilities

Among the books and resources I have searchable access to, I find only Prestige Class features, no feats (at least none that have [Mounted Combat](http://dndsrd.net/featsAll.html#mounted-combat) as a prerequisite, or that mention it or the word 'negate' in the description)

Here are the prestige class features:

Aglarondan Griffonrider (Unapproachable East, p18) gets

> **Improved Mounted Combat (Ex):** At 3rd, 5th, and 7th level, an Aglarondan griffonrider increases by one the number of Ride checks she may attempt each round to negate a hit against her mount (two times per round at 3rd, three times per round at 5th, and four times per round at 7th). The hit is negated if the griffonrider's Ride check result is greater than the attack roll.

Ashworm Dragoon (Sandstorm, p66) gets

> **Relentless Shield (Ex):** At 4th level and higher, you can make a Ride check after any attack that successfully strikes your ashworm mount, in an attempt to negate the hit on your ashworm. Normally, the Mounted Combat feat allows you to make this attempt only once per round. See the Mounted Combat feat, page 98 of the Player's Handbook, for details. In addition, you gain a +2 bonus on Ride checks made to negate an opponent's attack roll. This ability does not extend to any other type of mount.

Comment: Seriously, what's up with the entry requirements of the prestige class Aglarondan griffonrider? Those are *so* weird. (And I should've remembered the [ashworm dragoon](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/111062/8610)! Thank you!)

Comment: @HeyICanChan The only one that sticks out is Diplomacy; apparently it's for paladins who are all about the mount, not the smite or whatnot. Yer welcome! I found no spells with 'MC', 'ride check', 'negate a hit', 'negates a hit', 'negates the hit' or 'negate the hit', either. Chariot Combat (Sword and fist) would be unaffected by those class features (it and it's ilk are unreprinted, so part of 3.5, and are Handle Animal versions of some of the Ride feats)

Comment: O, I don't doubt your book-fu! Did you also confirm the absence of further abilities in, like, magazine and Web material, too? (And I meant the weirdness of the prestige class requiring a base attack bonus of +3 *and* 10 ranks in the skill Ride. What kind character *doesn't* have a +3 base attack bonus by the time they've 10 ranks in Ride so as to find himself heartbroken  by that silly Aglarondan griffonrider base attack bonus entry requirement?)

Comment: Let's not forget the Cunning Brilliance ability of the level 19 factotum. There is also Temporal Reiteration, but that would undo the effects of the previous usage.

Comment: @nijineko Not that any rider is going to *take* 19 levels of factotum, but how would cunning brilliance help? It's standard (not prestige) class features only.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Unfortunately, I was unable to search through non-book sources, so magazines and web resources are not included. (Aha, yep that's weird. It's unupdated 3.0 from FR, so maybe it's just lower editing standards)

Comment: @HeyICanChan Oh, I've never played one so I wasn't aware it was restricted in that way. I see the relevant text now that I've looked it up. I'll keep thinking about it.

Comment: So I thought I had something in the saddle of the *saddle of the inspired mount* (*Complete Psionic* 115) (5,400 gp; 30 lbs.). Alas, it was not meant to be. It seems only an ashworm mount can be defended an unlimited number of times *via* the feat Mounted Combat, darn it.