# Min INT score needed to read

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters, ability-scores

What's the minimum Intelligence score needed by a creature for that creature to be capable of reading/being taught to read?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## There isn't one

While creatures with Int less than 3 rarely speak a language, they don't never do so-- for example an Int 7 half-orc fighter who is subjected to *Bestow Curse* targeting Intelligence drops to 1 Int, but suffers no penalties for this beyond the lowered modifier on intelligence-based skill checks and other rolls specifically using intelligence.  Speaking a language and lacking the ability to be illiterate (such as a Barbarian acquires at 1st level regardless of Int) is what is needed to read a language, not any particular amount of Int; Speak Language says:

> A literate character (anyone but a barbarian who has not spent skill points to become literate) can read and write any language she speaks. Each language has an alphabet, though sometimes several spoken languages share a single alphabet.

Even mindless creatures like constructs can read, as long as they speak or understand a language, so not even '1' can be a prerequisite, though 'non-zero' would be a pretty good limit, since 0 Int incapacitates you.

Note that Speak Language's statement that *only* barbarians can be illiterate isn't *quite* true.  Unearthed Arcana provides, for example, the 'Illiterate' flaw.